# Does the word distribution in the Torah follow Zipfs law?

Tags: words

Does the word distribution in the Torah (ie the Pentateuch) follow [Zipfs law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZipfsLaw.html) where the frequency of a word's occurrence is inversely proportional to its statistical rank (ie does the 2nd most commonly used word occur 1/2 as often as the 1st, the 3rd most commonly used word occur 1/3 as often etc.)

Comment: Zipfs is only for the English language. In Hebrew, words are used much less frequently, as the nouns and verbs are compounded.

Comment: @lionscribe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law#Statistical_explanation Zipf's Law is not just for English, but for most languages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not linked to juaism

Comment: Could you [edit] in some indication of why, from the point of view of Judaism, you are (or anyone else could be) interested in knowing the answer to this?

Comment: I guess this english one doesn't follow it?  (I doubt any in any language does) http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Popular-Bible-Words.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not yet clear why, from the point if view of Judaism, someone would want to know this.

Comment: @IsaacMoses this information can be used in a discussion of biblical criticism/authorship. For example one could argue that if the bible does not follow Zipfs law then it is supernatural in authorship. Whether or not that is a sound argument is besides the point.